# Wrapping text around a displayed equation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, wrap

I have something like the following in a tex document:

```
some text ...

\[ T_y = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
          x + \alpha & \mbox{if $\alpha = \beta$}\\
          x^2 + \beta & \mbox{else} \end{array} \right. \]

some text again ...
```

**Question:** is it possible that the formula is adjusted at left and the second test comes in front of the formula (at right), and not immediately under it ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Would you try making your question clearer? It's not clear what text you're referring to.

Comment: What do you mean with 'above it'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you might like the `wrapfig` package for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}    % for cases environment (and lots more)
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % for wrapfigure environment
\usepackage{lipsum}     % for sample text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.5\textwidth}
\begin{equation}
 T_y = 
    \begin{cases}
          x + \alpha & \text{if $\alpha = \beta$}\\
          x^2 + \beta & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{wrapfigure}

\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, is it also possible to reduce the white space on top and bottom of the formula ? It takes a large space here.

Comment: @user995434 have a look at [the documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf) you can change the 'overhang' for example

Comment: I tried to change the overhang and the number of lines but it does not reduce the space in "top" of the formula

Comment: You can always add extra negative space. Try `\lipsum[3]
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{l}{.5\textwidth}
\vspace{-\baselineskip}
\begin{equation}
 T_y = 
    \begin{cases}
          x + \alpha & \text{if $\alpha = \beta$}\          x^2 + \beta & \text{else}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{wrapfigure}`

Comment: @user995434 I think you're looking for `\abovedisplayskip`; see [Herber's Mathmode document](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/mathmode/Mathmode.pdf)

Comment: @cmhughes Actually `\abovedisplayskip` (and `\abovedisplayshortskip`) do nothing here.