# Wrapping text around a displayed equation2

Tags: equations, minipage, wrapfigure

I found [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61771/wrapping-text-around-a-displayed-equation) to explain some details of some equations. 
In the first case I added `\begin{minipage}[h]{0.95\textwidth}.....`
while the second case is taken from the previous discussion.

I'm not very sure if this is correct. could you give any suggestions? thanks

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scale[2]{\vstretch{#1}{\hstretch{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\ssp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime}}}} %% scala il simbolo prime
\newcommand\sspp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime\prime}}}}

\newcommand*{\Fra}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\ccdot}{\,\mathrm{\!\cdot\!}}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[h]{0.95\textwidth}
In particolare possono essere evidenziati due casi:\\
\vspace{-25pt}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}
        \begin{align}
        F_{rd}^2 = \Fra{\Delta{U^2}}{g\,H\,\Fra{\Delta{\rho}}{\rho}}\tag{\ref{eq090}}
        \end{align}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{enumerate}
        \item in cui si abbiano due densità uguali, $\Delta{\rho}=0$ ed essendo a denominatore fa andare il valore del \emph{Numero di Froude} infinito;
        \item quanto $\Delta{\rho}\rightarrow\infty$ ( caso impossibile) allora $Fr_{rd}^2\rightarrow 0$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}\vspace{5pt}

Da questo si capisce che usare l'inverso di Froude al quadrato sarebbe più razionale, in particolare viene utilizzato all'interno del numero di Richardson.\\
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}
    \begin{align}
    F_{rd}^2 = \Fra{\Delta{U^2}}{g\,H\,\Fra{\Delta{\rho}}{\rho}}\tag{\ref{eq090}}
    \end{align}
\end{wrapfigure}
In particolare possono essere evidenziati due casi:
\begin{enumerate}
    \item in cui si abbiano due densità uguali, $\Delta{\rho}=0$ ed essendo a denominatore fa andare il valore del \emph{Numero di Froude} infinito;
    \item quanto $\Delta{\rho}\rightarrow\infty$ ( caso impossibile) allora $Fr_{rd}^2\rightarrow 0$
\end{enumerate}
\vspace{10pt}
Da questo si capisce che usare l'inverso di Froude al quadrato sarebbe più razionale, in particolare viene utilizzato all'interno del numero di Richardson.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what is the intention of `\begin{minipage}[h]{0.95\textwidth}` ? `minipage` does not have a `h` option, and this just indents everything by a paragraph indent and reduces the width of the text by 5% ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was wrong writing the minipage, the h should not be put

Comment: but what is the intention of the minipage? you could delete it and get the same result, but with the normal page margins restored.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not get the same result. obviously I inserted the two codes to highlight that I tried the two options, which obviously are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not clear what layout you want but perhaps

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{graphicx,wrapfig}
\usepackage{mwe} 
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\scale[2]{\vstretch{#1}{\hstretch{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand\ssp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime}}}} %% scala il simbolo prime
\newcommand\sspp[1]{#1^{\scale{.8}{\scriptstyle{\prime\prime}}}}

\newcommand*{\Fra}[2]{\frac{#1}{#2}} 
\newcommand{\ccdot}{\,\mathrm{\!\cdot\!}}

\graphicspath{ {./img/} }

\begin{document}

%??? does nothing useful \begin{minipage}[h]{0.95\textwidth}
In particolare possono essere evidenziati due casi:% don't end a paragrapg with \\
% dont't need negative space \vspace{-25pt}
% no need for wrapfig\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{.3\textwidth}

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
     % don't use align for single line equations   \begin{align}
\[
% mathrm for multi-letter identifiers
        F_{\mathrm{rd}}^2 = \Fra{\Delta{U^2}}{g\,H\,\Fra{\Delta{\rho}}{\rho}}
% this looks strange but I leave it
\tag{\ref{eq090}}
\]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
        \item in cui si abbiano due densità uguali, $\Delta{\rho}=0$ ed essendo a denominatore fa andare il valore del \emph{Numero di Froude} infinito;
        \item quanto $\Delta{\rho}\rightarrow\infty$ ( caso impossibile) allora $Fr_{rd}^2\rightarrow 0$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

%\vspace{5pt}

Da questo si capisce che usare l'inverso di Froude al quadrato sarebbe più razionale, in particolare viene utilizzato all'interno del numero di Richardson.\\
\bigskip\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{.3\textwidth}
\[
    F_{\mathrm{rd}}^2 = \Fra{\Delta{U^2}}{g\,H\,\Fra{\Delta{\rho}}{\rho}}\tag{\ref{eq090}}
\]
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{.6\textwidth}
In particolare possono essere evidenziati due casi:

\begin{enumerate}
    \item in cui si abbiano due densità uguali, $\Delta{\rho}=0$ ed essendo a denominatore fa andare il valore del \emph{Numero di Froude} infinito;
    \item quanto $\Delta{\rho}\rightarrow\infty$ ( caso impossibile) allora $Fr_{rd}^2\rightarrow 0$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}

Da questo si capisce che usare l'inverso di Froude al quadrato sarebbe più razionale, in particolare viene utilizzato all'interno del numero di Richardson.

\end{document}
```

Comment: CarliseThank you for the precise and very useful explanation. question: why can not '\ begin {align}' be used for single line equations? I normally used \ begin {equation} \ begin {align}, after I [read this possibility](https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath) that I find comfortable, but it is not correct.

Comment: @Antonio an `align` is always full width (for technical reasons to support the align constructs) so the usual adjustment tex makes for spacing around short equations never happens, so you get much better spacing around `equation` or `\[`

Comment: I have seen that using this method `\[.equation \label{.}\]` the label references of the equations are not included in the pdf print. 
in particular I'm using `\usepackage {showkeys}`. this is very useful for me to remember the references of the various equations. 
this does not create problems with `\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}..equation.` . 
I also saw that I receive an error in the `amsmath` package about the `\ tag {\ ref {eq090}}`, 
when I use it `\begin{equation} \begin{aligned}.equation.\tag{\ref{eq090}}`,the error is canceled if I use it `\[..\tag{\ref{eq090}}\]`

Comment: @Antonio no see any basic latex tutorial, use `\begin{equation}a=b\label{zzz}\end{equation}` if you want a numbered eauation you can reference, `\[a=b\]` is fro un-numbered equations (same as `align` giving numbers and `align*` no numbers)

Comment: @Antonio the construct  `\tag{\ref{eq090}}` is _very_ odd, you are forcing one equation to get the same label as some other equation?

Comment: Yes, I use the Tag when I need to refer to an equation written in another paragraph or chapter. it's a method I use a few times.Thanks for your directions. Thank you for your explanations. It is always pleasant to read your suggestions.