# Strange interaction between aligned environment and wrapfigure

Tags: align, wrapfigure

I am attempting to wrap document text around the equation below using the following code.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{left}{0pt}
    $$ \begin{aligned}
        \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}\frac{\pi}{16} &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}\right)}\cdot         \cancelto{2}{32}}{(2i+17)\cancel{\pi}}\frac{\cancel{\pi}}{\cancel{16}} \\
        &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15}\frac{2\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{2i+17}.
    \end{aligned} $$
\end{wrapfigure}
```

However, when I compile the document, I receive errors "`\begin{align}` only allowed in math environment" and "missing $ inserted." I've tried using `equation*`, as I've seen it used in the `wrapfigure` environment ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61771/wrapping-text-around-a-displayed-equation)), but none of them will give me multiline equations.

I'm using Overleaf with the pdfLaTeX compiler, and the document still compiles and actually displays correctly, but I'm not sure why the error is there.[image: Compiled document with correct formatting]

P.S. I apologize if my formatting is poor, this is my first Tex.SE, and if my question has a very simple answer, I am very new to LaTeX.

Comment: Regarding: "I receive errors" and "the document still compiles and actually displays correctly": Even if you get something that on first glance resembles a pdf file, there can still be issues with it. After an error, TeX only tries to recover enough to syntax check more of the file, it does not try to make sensible output after an error.

Comment: [What are the differences between $$, \[, align, equation and displaymath?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/134144)  might be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use a displaystyle syntax, but a simple `$ ... $`. This insertion can also be done with the `\InsertBoxL` command, from the plainTeX macro package `insbox`.

This command has two mandatory arguments: the number of unshortened lines before insertion, and the contents of the box, plus an optional argument: the number of supplementary shortened lines, in case TeX has computed erroneously the necessary number of short lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}% for 'vmatrix*' and 'align*' env.
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{cancel}
\input{insbox} % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}[7]{l}{0pt}
$ \begin{aligned}
        \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}\frac{\pi}{16} &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}\right)}\cdot \cancelto{2}{32}}{(2i+17)\cancel{\pi}}\frac{\cancel{\pi}}{\cancel{16}} \\
        &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15}\frac{2\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{2i+17}.
    \end{aligned} $
\end{wrapfigure}
\noindent
\lipsum[2]
\vskip 1cm
\InsertBoxL{0}{$ \begin{aligned}
        \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}\frac{\pi}{16} &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15} \frac{\cos{\left(\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}\right)}\cdot \cancelto{2}{32}}{(2i+17)\cancel{\pi}}\frac{\cancel{\pi}}{\cancel{16}} \\
        &= \sum\limits_{i=0}^{15}\frac{2\cos{\frac{(2i+17)\pi}{32}}}{2i+17}.
    \end{aligned} $}[2]
\noindent
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Do]